# How to test database behavior?

Tags: database-performance

Dear all, Is there any tool available that can check all databases in a system by sending some sample data to the database to make sure that data transaction is occurring correctly. Moreover, the sample data should be invisible an inaccessible from the outside world. If you have any idea please help.

**Update**

Thank you for your answer. But I have some questions regarding your given answer.

- Is the above solution is applicable to MySQL and SQLite?
- If so, then where to open the database.txt file?

By the way, I am using WampServer2 for the system and my database is MySQL

Comment: @Esika please edit your question to add more information. Alternatively, you can comment on the answers, but do not post an answer that isn't an answer. Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) create  database.txt file and
>   change file type with name
>   database.udl
>
> 2) open the file
>
> 3) select tab provider
>
> 4) select Microsoft Ole Db Provider
>   for ODBC Drivers and press Next
>
> 5) write . or (local) in Use data
>   source name
>
> 6) select database name in (Enter the
>   initial catalog to use)
>
> 7) Test Connection

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have some questions regarding your given answer. 1. Is the above solution is applicable to MySQL and SQLite?
2. If so, then where to open the database.txt file? By the way, I am using WampServer2 for the system and my database is MySQL

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have some questions regarding your given answer. 1. Is the above solution is applicable to MySQL and SQLite? 2. If so, then where to open the database.txt file? By the way, I am using WampServer2 for the system and my database is MySQL

Comment: I don't know , how create sqlConnection for SQLight and MySQL.

Comment: could you please tell me for which system you provide the above solution?